# C# XNA Network Game Without LIVE

Tags: c#, networking, xna, live

I have made a game in C# with XNA. And I would like to make it playable online.

I want to be able to host a game on one machine and be able to connect to this game on other machines. Kinda like a listen server in Half Life.

This might seem like a pretty common problem that should have been solved a million times. But I have googled my ass off and i cant really seem to find any useful information.

**I want to know exactly what I would need, concerning network-stuff, in order to create an online game with XNA, without using the microsoft-Live thingy.**

1. A Library? the using-thing located in top of a class.
2. Code for initializing this stuff
3. How to look for another computer playing this game.
4. How to get/send data between the computers.
5. On which client are things calculated. If one guy would fire a bullet, should this bullet be created as an object on both clients? Or is one having the object,(checking for collisions etc.) and the other one just gets positions for draw?

I would like someone who has made a game like this to answer, what would be a standard approach.

Comment: Try asking on GameDev.StackExchange.com, they specialize in this kind of thing.

Comment: Your question is way too wide, what you want here is a tutorial on managing networking between two application, we can't just google that for you. Also, that using-thing located in top of a class isn't a library, its just a code shortcut. Your libraries are in the reference section of VS.

Comment: You might want to clarify if this is meant to run on XBox 360, WP7 or PC or other platform via Monogame or somesuch. The answer will vary based on this information.

Comment: C# sockets library may be too "low level", but it's one of the ways.

Comment: @Kelkk - Code the Client and Server...I suggest just using the library that already exists if you know nothing about networking, if you implement it yourself, I guarantee you it will be wrong.  The fact you call it a "using thingy" means you have no business programming.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in XNA libraries are Live-focused, so you'll either have to live with that, or use a different network library.

The .NET UdpClient and Socket libraries are pretty straightforward.

Alternatively, have a look at the [Lindgren open source network library](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/). It includes some extension methods for sending XNA types like Matrix, Vector3, etc. which can be useful when you're getting started.

Comment: The Lidgren library looks good, i'll check it out. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer for a question about making an MMO using lidgren, as mentioned above. It's got a few links to resources you can use to learn how to use it. I've used it personally to have a small test app with 5 users running around together, but I haven't taken it any further than that just yet.

[Massive multiplayer in xna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033094/massive-multiplayer-in-xna/10042968#10042968)

Comment: thanks, this looks pretty good, i'll check it out